# Local CI-like tool

Tags: continuous-integration, scripting

I'm looking for something like a Continous Integration tool like Jenkins or Bamboo. But I don't want something that big and heavy, it shouldn't be like a server. Just an eleborated batch tool (first do this, then do this, then do this...)

Comment: Your question lacks lots of details.

Comment: What's wrong with Jenkins? Which o/s (if Windows, use https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html to get a server on localhost - it is trivial to install). Must it be free (use the "gratis" tag), or do you have a budget?  You will probably expand to use Jenkins sooner or later, so why not start now? Btw, which language(s) are you developing in?

Comment: Because Jenkins is a whole server server and all, I'm just looking for something stand alone. I'm developing in PhoneGap on Windows.

Comment: One of the main advantage to Continuous Integration systems is the ability for many developers to contribute code and have that code built on some regular basis.  A local CI tool implies one developer.  How does that become useful?

Comment: I'm really unclear what the difference is between what you asked, and a makefile.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Yes, maybe it's one of these kitchen-sink build tools such as [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html) that Ravenix is after?  The "like a server" bits of Jenkins are very powerful, but take them away and I doubt there's much left at all which Gradle can't do.

Answer (score 1):

If Linux: http://linci.tp23.org/ might fit the bill, it is written pretty much in bash.
Server components are `tsp` and `cron` so that it limits running too many jobs at the same time.  Designed to resolve the problem that Jenkins is too big to run on micro instances.